# In Git is it possible to treat my uncommitted changes as merge conflicts?

Tags: git

I made some changes to a file (uncommitted), and want to revert some changes, but not others.  VSCode provides a very nice set of buttons for resolving merge conflicts, which would be much more efficient than pulling up the diff of the file and copying over the bits I want to keep.  Is there a way to treat a diff file or an applied stash of a file as a set of merge conflicts with HEAD?

```sh
git stash -- path/to/my/file
git stash apply
git stash apply
```

This obviously won't work because the changes to my file are identical to the changes being applied, which presents no merge conflicts.

Comment: What you are describing is normally done (with IDEs that I've seen) diffing with current revision, which would highlight all the differences... then you could go through each one of the bliocks and decide if you want to "revert"or not by using a single button on each block.... don't know what the UI would be like in VS but I expect something similar would be available.

Comment: VS Code doesn't have a single button per change, unfortunately.  There's a single button for deletes, but not one for adds.  I can, however, select all the changes I want reverted with my mouse and then revert selected changes.  Still not ideal.

Comment: vscode doesn't have any way to do `git checkout --patch`, or `git reset --patch`‚ or `git add --patch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This might be round about way of doing it.

- Checkout a new `temp` branch from `current` branch.
- Commit all your changes.
- Pull the code from `origin` to `temp` brach.
- All the merge conflicts will show up in `VS code` now.
- Add/Remove changes what you need.
- Commit the final version to the same `temp` branch.
- Switch to the `original` branch again.
- Do `squash merge` of `temp` branch to `original` branch (`git merge --squash temp`)
- Unstage the changes.

Finally, you will end up what you want.

Instead of going through all these steps, you can use `VS Code` or built-in `git gui` tool(`gitk`) for comparison.

Comment: Clever.  It'd be pretty easy to turn that into a bash script.  I'll try it in a little bit